# Is there a way to go through all combinations of a list of numbers without nested loops?

Tags: c++, combinations

My problem is a bit hard to explain, so I will do my best.  I'm writing a program that will take a target number and a list of other numbers.  I want it to add all possible combinations of numbers from the list until a combination of numbers from the list sums to be the same as the target number.  For example, if the target number is 6 and the list provided has the numbers <2, 3, 4, 5>, then the program will print the solution being 2+4=6.

I currently have the program set up with 4 nested loops where the outermost loop checks combinations with the first number as constant.  The second loop holds the second number constant, and likewise for the other two.  If the target number was 20 for the above list, the program would check in the following manner:

```
2
2+3
2+3+4
2+3+4+5
2+3+5
2+4
2+4+5
2+5
3
3+4
3+4+5
3+5
4
4+5
5
```

Then it would return a message saying no solutions were found.  This works okay for small lists, but would not work very well if the list contained many small numbers and the target number was a high one.  Since the program only has four loops, it can only add 4 numbers at most.

I can't help but thinking that there must be a better way to do this, because for longer lists, the only solution would be to make more nested loops, which isn't practical.  Is there a way to go through all combinations of a list of numbers without nested loops?

I hope that this was easy to understand.  If you'd like to see my code, let me know.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: This problem, known as [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), is NP complete, which means that even with the best algorithms there are always cases which are really expensive to solve once the size of the problem grows.

Comment: Yes, use recursion. Recursion can handle any length of list you like.

Comment: CodesInChaos, I did not know there was a name for that problem.  That should be an interesting read later.
@john, I didn't even think of using recursion, but that is a brilliant idea and works excellently. Thank you very much for that bit of advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a recursive approach like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<bool> active_pos;
vector<int> input;

int recurse (int current_sum, int target_sum, int length) {
    if (length < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        if (active_pos[i]) {
            continue;
        }

        active_pos[i] = true;

        int tmp_sum = current_sum + input[i];


        if (tmp_sum == target_sum) {
            return tmp_sum;
        }

        int next_sum = recurse(tmp_sum, target_sum, length-1);
        if (next_sum == target_sum) {
            return next_sum;
        }

        active_pos[i] = false;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    input.push_back(2);
    input.push_back(3);
    input.push_back(4);
    input.push_back(5);
    input.push_back(6);

    int length = input.size();
    active_pos.resize(length);

    int res = recurse(0, 10, length);

    cout << "Result is: " << res << endl;
    cout << "Used numbers are: " <<  endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        if (active_pos[j]) {
            cout << input[j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The function `recurse()` calls itself and decrements the `length` parameters by one for each time. A vector keeps track of the values which are already taken.

If an instance of `recurse()` finds a matching sum, it returns that value. If not, it returns -1. If the final result is -1, no matches were found.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up using a recursive approach, so being able to reference to this was of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this from the other direction....add all of the numbers from the list together, and if it doesn't equal the target value, your done....if the addition of the list is larger than the target, then start to remove items from the start of you list until you match the target value.  If you don't match, (skips by the target value) and the addition value become smaller than your target value, then handle that scenario appropriately.

This should only require 1 loop.

Comment: This was actually my initial idea when I was presented with the problem.  Keeping track of the numbers started to get tedious though, so I used the loops instead.  Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

You could represent each combination as `N` one-bit values, set if that element should be in the combination. Then iterating over all combinations is equivalent to counting from 1 to 2<sup>N</sup>, with an inner loop to add up the values corresponding to the set bits.

If the set size is 64 or less, then you do this very easily with a `uint64_t` loop counter. If it's larger, then you probably won't live long enough to see the result anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're saying, but if I am understanding it right, I was going to try that but thought that it would take a while.  However, I was able to use recursion suggested by John and Atle, so that worked.  Thank you for your response though!